# Is the one-dimensional time-independent Schrödinger equation solvable in potential (1+Tanh(x+1))(-1+Tanh(x-1))

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

The one dimensional time-independent Schrödinger equation reads:

\begin{equation}
-\frac{h^2}{2m}\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}+U(x)~\psi=E~\psi
\end{equation}

where $\psi(x)$ is the wave function, U(x) is the potential, E is the eigen-energy. $\hbar=1$ is the Plank constant, $m=1$ is the mass of the particle.

Under the potential of

\begin{equation}
U(x)=(1+Tanh(x))(-1+Tanh(x))
\end{equation}

the Schrödinger can be solved analytically,

\begin{equation}
\psi(x)=C_1P_1^{i\sqrt{2E}}(Tanh(x))+C_2Q_1^{i\sqrt{2E}}(Tanh(x))
\end{equation}

where P and Q are the associated Legendre polynomial $P_n^m(x)$ and associated Legendre function of the second kind $Q_n^m(x)$.

**Question**:

If we have a slightly different potential

\begin{equation}
U(x)=(1+Tanh(x+1))(-1+Tanh(x-1))
\end{equation}

can the Schrödinger also be solved analytically?